# How do I make music and videos from an external hard drive show up on the lens filters?

Tags: unity, external-hdd, lenses, media

Using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Unity. I keep all my music and movies on an external hdd and I was wondering if there was a way to make the media on the hdd show up on the dash and its lens filters.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and import your entire music collection to The default Music player in Ubuntu.

This will expose all your music to Unity lens and they should show up on dash. :)

Answer (score 0):

If music is not in the Music folder,  and if movies are not in the Video  folder,  they will not appear in the Dash, However if you listen or watch something from the external hard drive the files start to appear in the Dash in the recently used category.